# What does $w=1$ mean in cosmology/inflation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

I got a problem where I had to calculate the equation of state of a scalar factor $a\propto t^q$. I found that, solving the Friedmann equation, $\rho_\Phi=\frac{3M_p^2q^2}{t^2}$, which is equal to $\rho_\Phi=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\Phi}^2+V(\Phi)$, so you can get $p_\Phi=\rho_\Phi-2V(\Phi)$, and finally, after substituting $\rho_\Phi$, we get $w=1-\frac{2V(\Phi)t^2}{3M_p^2q^2}$. If $q\rightarrow\infty$, then $w\rightarrow1$, so it means that $V(\Phi)=0$. Does that mean that $\Phi$ is also equivalent to zero since it does not have energy?

Comment: Since $a \propto t^{\frac{2}{3(1+w)}}$ for $a∝t^q$ you need $w=\frac{2-3 q}{3 q}$.

Comment: It seems you used $p_{\Phi} = w \rho_{\Phi}$. This relationship is true for the cosmological pressure and the energy density of the Universe, since you assume it is a perfect fluid. It is not true for the density and pressure of a single scalar field $\Phi$, unless it is the only type of matter that exists, and is uniformly distributed in all of space. If that is the case, you should obtain $w=-1$, since the Universe will be undergoing inflation. If you use the correct relation between $q$ and $w$ that Yukterez mentions, you'll see that this is what you get for $q \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @rhomaios Scalar field domination only leads to $w=-1$ if the scalar field's potential energy dominates. For example, an oscillating scalar field leads to $w=0$ while a kinetic energy-dominated scalar field leads to $w=1$.

Comment: Yes, that was my assumption because OP mentions inflation and examines the limit $q \rightarrow \infty$ (and I presume $\Phi$ refers to some kind of inflaton field).